# Convert java looping into JSTL <c:forEach>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I used java, and i want to convert it into jsp using c:forEach

```
 int supplierList = 40;
 for (int a = 0; a < supplierList ; a++) 
 {

 }
```

[Here is my java code screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICSHg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<c:forEach items="${bean.getFunctions()}" var="func">
    <c:if test="${func.key=='Search'}">
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>`

in here bean.getFunctions() will return a map. When looping each element will assign to var.